# Website Loading Issue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Okay so when I use the bookmarked link for my website it works just fine. But when I try to go to my website from this page

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.navjeevenmann.bookofthemonth

Right at the bottom it says Developer Website and when you click on it the loading icon just goes forever, but if you right-click and click open In new tab it works just fine.

Here is the Javascript:

```
  function myFunction() {
   myVar = setTimeout(showPage,1500);
  }

 function showPage() {
 document.getElementById("ss").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("Text").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("main").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("Menu").style.display = "block";

 }
```

My Website:[Click Here](http://jeevenmann.ca)

Comment: which browser you'r using? what error in console if that's a javascript error

Answer (score 0):

It loads fine on my side, although I did notice that a script is blocked by my ad blocker:

http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js

Do you have an adBlocker installed?

Chrome is fine with it but it may be that other browsers halt the rest of the JavaScript execution due to this.